# Output length of recurrent neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I have written two LSTM RNN codes in python that do sequence-prediction. I have a simple sequence (say a noisy-sinewave) and I am training my networks to "predict" future values along the sinewave. My first code just predicts the single next value (so there is only 1 output neuron), while the second code I wrote predicts the 5-next values (i.e. 5 output neurons). To get the prediction 5-steps in advance for the first code I need to call the predict function several times (utilising the previous predict's output).

Both cases seem to work quite well, but what I'm really trying to work out is which of these two network architectures is best for this problem. There is practically nothing in the literature comparing these output models.

Answer (score 0):

I think using output as an input is not a good idea for this problem. Your output will always have some error and it might increase with each step ( Steady state error ).

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense but I wanted to check.